# Hibernate criteria how to get rows with max column value

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have a table like below:

```
       user_id   number
        1         10
        2         17
        1         12
        2         18
```

I mean one user can have more than one row.
I have to reach following result:

```
       user_id   number
        1         12
        2         18
```

How can I achive this with hibernate criteria?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this.

```
Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(User.class);
cr.setProjection(
         Projections.projectionList()
            .add(Projections.groupProperty("userId"))
            .add(Projections.max("number"))
);
```

This is an untested code.

Answer (score 2):

```
select u.id, max(u.number) from User u group by u.id
```

This is the HQL query you need. I don't see any point of translating this to criteria, but if you really want to do it, it shouldn't be hard. You'll need to use projections from the `Projections` class.

Comment: Thanks but I really need criteria way of this. I could not translate it to criteria either.

Comment: Show a bit of effort. What have you tried? Where are you stuck?